# Exclude part for all IE-versions in typo3

Tags: html, internet-explorer, typo3, conditional-comments

I would like to temporary exclude all version of the Internet Explorer (IE) from a specific part in my typo3 html file. 
I tried to comment it out this way:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<p>Some content here</p>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

This method does not work.

Does anyone has a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Conditional comments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) (`<!--[if !IE]> -->`) have been removed in Internet Explorer 10, so, it only works before IE9 version.

To detect all IE versions using JavaScript, I suggest you could check the [userAgent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) string. Under the IE 9 version, you could use the conditional comments to control the comments, for IE 9+ version, you could use JavaScript to hide the comments.

Please check the following sample:

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
<p id="iecontent">Some IE content here</p>
<!-- <![endif]-->

<script>
    //userAgent in IE7 WinXP returns: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)
    //userAgent in IE11 Win7 returns: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1)
        var detectIEregexp = /MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/ //test for MSIE x.x
    else // if no "MSIE" string in userAgent
        var detectIEregexp = /Trident.*rv[ :]*(\d+\.\d+)/ //test for rv:x.x or rv x.x where Trident string exists

    if (detectIEregexp.test(navigator.userAgent)) { //if some form of IE
        var ieversion = new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number
       //define a flag to check whether IE version is IE 9+
        var flag = false;
        if (ieversion >= 12)
        {
            document.write("You're using IE12 or above");
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (ieversion >= 11)
        {
            document.write("You're using IE11 or above")
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (ieversion >= 10)
        {
            document.write("You're using IE10 or above")
            flag = true;
        }
        else if (ieversion >= 9)
            document.write("You're using IE9 or above")
        else if (ieversion >= 8)
            document.write("You're using IE8 or above")
        else if (ieversion >= 7)
            document.write("You're using IE7.x")
        else if (ieversion >= 6)
            document.write("You're using IE6.x")
        else if (ieversion >= 5)
            document.write("You're using IE5.x")

        if (flag)
            document.getElementById("iecontent").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.write("n/a")
    }
</script>
```